# One button each row in a table cell

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place 2 buttons into a table cell with JavaScript

I have something like this:

```
var table_cell = document.getElementById("table_cell")
var button_A = document.createElement("input")
button_A.setAttribute("value","BUTTON A")
button_A.setAttribute("type","button")
var button_B = document.createElement("input")
button_B.setAttribute("value","BUTTON A")
button_B.setAttribute("type","button")
table_cell.appendChild(button_A)
table_cell.appendChild(button_B)
```

buttons get lined up side by side, rather than one up and one down.
I am trying to make it so that there is one button per level

```
 _____________   
|  _________  |   
| |_________| |     
|  _________  |   
| |_________| |     
|_____________|
```

rather than

```
 __________________________
|  _________   _________   |
| |_________| |_________|  |
|__________________________|
```

I have tried appending a textnode on to table_cell that contains escape characters like "\r\n" and "&#10&38" but none works.

I would appreciate if there is a solution with JS

Comment: Add a breaking space (`<br/>`) in between the buttons?

Comment: Is CSS not an option?

Comment: hmm, I wonder how would I archive with CSS?

Comment: @user1486030 With the appropriate selector for the button, I think `display:block` would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `<br>` tag between the buttons

```
table_cell.appendChild(button_A);
table_cell.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
table_cell.appendChild(button_B);
```

Comment: A <b> tag wouldn't help ;)

Comment: Yes, confirmed.
document.createElement('br') works!
Thank you Musa!

Comment: Too bad that SO doesn't allow to edit less than 6 chars even though if that makes perfect sense !!

Comment: @Musa I referred to the typo in your first sentence where you wrote <b> instead of <br>.

Comment: @Musa SebastianG was talking about the spelling :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
button_A.style.display = 'block';
button_B.style.display = 'block';
```

But using CSS would probably be best:

```
input[type="button"] {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if the CSS solution is posted as well

Answer (score 0):

```
table_cell.appendChild(button_A)
table_cell.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
table_cell.appendChild(button_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line break (`<br />`) element:

```
var table_cell = document.getElementById("table_cell");
var button_A = document.createElement("input");
button_A.setAttribute("value","BUTTON A");
button_A.setAttribute("type","button");
var button_B = document.createElement("input");
button_B.setAttribute("value","BUTTON A");
button_B.setAttribute("type","button");
var newline = document.createElement("br"); // <-- Add a newline
table_cell.appendChild(button_A);
table_cell.appendChild(newline); // <-- and append
table_cell.appendChild(button_B);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FdkM7/)**